# Remove class from all and add to one clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a function where I want to remove an active class from all elements and add it to the one which was just clicked. Problem is that when I click the element all of them get the active class. Please see the code below.

```
var pagination = $('.pagination div');

function pager() {
    pagination.removeClass('active', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
}

$('.pagination div').on("click", function (){
    pager();
});
```

I could use the code below, which works actually, but the reason I want to use the above one is to have possibility adding other functions in it which will be called later on click.

```
$('.pagination div').on('click',function(){
  $('.pagination div').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

HTML if needed

```
<div class="pagination">
    <div class="pagination1"></div>
    <div class="pagination2"></div>
    <div class="pagination3"></div>
    <div class="pagination4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The fact you don't aim the function to a particular element make this function un scopable, which means you don't have any information of which element in particular you clicked.

Comment: Setup a second `on` listener. You'll have many functions assigned to one `click`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to use the above one is to have possibility adding other
>   functions in it which will be called later

Try this:

```
function pager(el) {
    pagination.removeClass('active', function(){
        $(el).addClass('active');
    });
}

$('.pagination div').on("click", function (){
    pager(this);
});
```

Comment: still its just same as other one.

Comment: Thanks :) Works great!

Answer (score 7):

By using a separate function, you are losing your reference to the current object (this). You will need to use a parameter to get your way working.

```
function pager(element) {
    pagination.removeClass('active', function(){
        element.addClass('active');
    });
}

$('.pagination div').on("click", function (){
    pager($(this));
});
```

Comment: I have chosen the first answer as the right one, but thanks for the explanation. Although it worked I did not get how :)

Comment: @EmilGurbanov No problem, glad that you got it working. To further explain: during an onclick event, `$(this)` references the item clicked. When you call another function, you no longer have that reference as you have left the onclick function. By passing the referenced element to your function, you still have access to the clicked item.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.pagination').on('click', 'div', function(){
     $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var pagination = $('.pagination div');

function pager(selector) {
    $('.pagination div').removeClass('active');
    $(selector).addClass('active');
}

$('.pagination div').on("click", function (){
    pager(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pagination = $('.pagination div');

function pager(that) {

    pagination.removeClass('active', function(){
       that.addClass('active');
    });
}

$('.pagination div').on("click", function (){
    pager($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Editable JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rca1v5rs/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="pagination">
<div class="pagination1">Pagination 1</div>
<div class="pagination2">Pagination 2</div>
<div class="pagination3">Pagination 3</div>
<div class="pagination4">Pagination 4</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() { // DOM loaded event handler
    function pager (element) {
        $(".pagination div").removeClass("active");
        element.addClass("active");
    }

    $(".pagination div").click(function() {
        var element = $(this);

        pager(element);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
   color : red;
}
```

I used your function in 2 steps :

- First, I remove all `active` class by using `$(".pagination div").removeClass("active");` which actually apply this effect on all sub div
- then, I use the element passed through parameter to the function to scope it, and be able to add the proper class

Answer (score 0):

Use id for all the element then add active class to each element which has been click or use e.target this will track the current element

```
 $('.pagination').click(function(e){
    $('.pagination').removeClass('active');
    $(e.target).addClass('active');
});
```